# Is there a better way to display the filename in carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

At the moment

```
<%= link_to comment.file, comment.file_url %>
```

displays

```
/uploads/comment/file/6/IP___Addresses
```

Is there such thing as something like `comment.file.filename` ?

Is there a way to get the filename and display a link to that, so it would just say IPAddresses.txt and links to "/uploads/comment/file/6/IPAddresses" ?

Edit:

Figured it out

```
<%= link_to File.basename(comment.file.url), comment.file_url %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have used the *_identifier method, in your case:

```
comment.file_identifier
```